# How to instantiate a JavaScript class in another class?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently doing a school project, the project revolves around easy access to skills in an organisation. I have created a class called Employee, this class have a predefined set of employees stored in localStorage (because no access to databases). The list of employees is outputted via a function that creates a table of the list.

Now I want to create a class called Skills, I want the Skills class be instantiated in my Employee class. The purpose of this is that employees should be able to enter a site and write in their skills, the skills has to be stored to a employee and the saved in localStorage and the updated in the table.
 So my problem revolves around using the right syntax / method of instantiation a class into another class..

```
class Skills{
    constructor(sId){
        this.sId = sId;
    }
}
if (localStorage.getItem("Skills") == null) {
    var skillList =[];
    var skillListString = JSON.stringify(skillList);
    localStorage.setItem("skills",skillListString);
} else {
    var skillListString = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Skills"));    

class Employee {
    // vi bruger en constructor funktion for at lave en opskrift på objekter af en bestemt type.
    //this metoden benyttes til at referere til det tilhørende objekt
    constructor(name, gender, department, yy, email, skills) {
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.department = department;
        this.email = email;
        this.skills = [];

    }
}

//Employee Database "Localstorage"
if(localStorage.getItem("Employee") == null) {
    let employeeList = [];
    employeeList.push (new Employee("Simon", "Male", "HR", 1999, "2650@mail.dk"));
    employeeList.push (new Employee("Mads", "Male","IT", 1999,  "1234@email.com"));
    employeeList.push (new Employee("Jessica", "Female", "Sales",1998, "Mail2@mail.dk"));
    employeeList.push (new Employee("Benjamin", "Male","IT", 1997, "blabla@mail.dk"));

    if(localStorage.getItem("Employee") == null) {
        employeeListString = JSON.stringify(employeeList);
        localStorage.setItem("Employee", employeeListString);
        employeeList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Employee"));
    }
} else {
    employeeList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Employee"));
    document.querySelector("#employees").appendChild(buildTable(employeeList));
}
```

Comment: mention your previous programming language may help. I mean, your question doesn't sound like a problem at all in javascript world.

Comment: Same as instantiating it anywhere else, `new SomeClass()`.

Comment: You've shown that you know how to instantiate the `Employee` class in your code. Do the same with `Skills`.

Comment: @appleapple there is a JS tag ;)

Comment: @HereticMonkey my problem is that I can't figure out how I use my Skills class within my Employee Class

Comment: @BenjaminNielsen well, I mean you should mention the programming language you use **before** learning JavaScript.

Comment: @appleapple none? JS is my first language

Comment: It's not clear where you want to use `Skills` within your `Employee` class.

Comment: @BenjaminNielsen ahh, OK, then what makes you think *instantiate a JavaScript class in another class* has anything different than *instantiate a JavaScript class in top-level*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You instantiate a class from inside another class in the same way you always instantiate a class - with the keyword `new`.

Example:

```js
class Foo {}

class Bar {
  constructor() {
    this.foo = new Foo()
  }
}

bar = new Bar()
```

In terms of design you may find it best to 'inject' your classes dependencies. This typically leads to more testable and maintainable code. [clean-code-javascript](https://github.com/ryanmcdermott/clean-code-javascript#dependency-inversion-principle-dip) has some nice examples.

Example:

```js
class Foo {}

class Bar {
  constructor(foo) {
    this.foo = foo
  }
}

foo = new Foo()
bar = new Bar(foo)
```

Comment: I believe it should pass instance not type. (btw, I personally don't like DI)

Comment: @appleapple I believe I am passing an instance. The usefulness of DI will depend on the problem but it's still an important pattern to be aware of.

Comment: oh, my mistake.

Comment: @appleapple could you please elaborate as to why You don’t like DI. I thought that made for loose coupling ? Would appreciate your input!

Comment: @KevinGreetham I'm not really sure what I think that time. But (use this answer for example) basically if you create `Foo` only to feed `Bar`, better to let `Bar` decide which it want (as implementation detail). It's not like you can create arbitrary `Foo` that'd make `Bar` work, and most of the time there is only 1 reasonable `Foo` that fits.

Comment: @KevinGreetham loose coupling may sound good. but most of the time you just don't case about what's actually used. and if something specific is needed, it's unlikely the language doesn't provide a way to make a new class.

Comment: @KevinGreetham and although it's named **loose** coupling, it's actually **strong** couples `Bar` to the interface of `Foo`, which add an unnecessary constraint.

Comment: minor fix: although some may say it achieve loose coupling.

Comment: @appleapple thanks. I understand. However if Bar’s implementation depended on a number of different possible objects then D.I would then be far leased coupled. Correct ? And also if later down the line I wanted to add another object which could be passed into Bar, then I could quite easily?  Wouldn’t this make our apps easier to extend without having to change the internals of Bar? Thanks for your help here !

Comment: @KevinGreetham well actually not, you just change the dependency (coupling) from `Bar` to `IBarNeedThis` which actually *add* an interface *and* a dependency between `Bar` and that interface.

Comment: @KevinGreetham for the second part. It's not like it'd be any harder to change the code on demand (and I don't think the requirement *not change `Bar`* make much sense). And if the only reason is *may* need it in the future, the chances are it'd never happen, even if it does, at that point it may require more than whichever interface you can decide now (or even completely drop the use of `Foo`).

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely store instantiated classes as property:

```js
// create instance in constructor
class Human {
  constructor(name, cat_name) {
    this.name = name
    this.cat = new Cat(cat_name)
  }
}

// or pass already constructed instance
class Human
  constructor(name, cat) {
    this.name = name
    this.cat = cat
  }
}
```

But there is less obvious problem: JSON doesn't have custom types, therefore it could only store plain JS objects, arrays, and a few primitives, like strings and numbers.

So custom class (and especially class stored in a property) would not survive default serialization/deserialization roundtrip. You cannot store references as easily as you can with plain JS objects. You'd have to do it yourself, for example, you could transform each class to `{type:'human', fields: { name: 'John' }}` object that could be safely serialized to JSON.

```
class Human {
  constructor(name, cat) {
    this.name = name
    this.cat = cat
  }
  serialize() {
    return { type: 'Human', fields: { cat: this.cat.serialize(), name: this.name }}
  }
}
```

And then deserialize according to `type`, invoking constructors as needed.